# Try to convert text file to Excel

Tags: c#

I have text file like this:

```
VehicleReferenceKey:2365565656
DriverReferenceKey:965454545454
Latitude:30000


**

VehicleReferenceKey:96896A4607A6
DriverReferenceKey:96896A4607A6
Latitude:500


**

VehicleReferenceKey:822F5B18
DriverReferenceKey:822F5B18
Latitude:1000
```

I try To convert this text file to Excel
first i made an Class as

```
public class Item
{
    public string VehicleReferenceKey;
    public string DriverReferenceKey;
    public string  Latitude;
}
```

then i read all text file and looping of it as

```
var lines = File.ReadAllLines(fileName);
for (var i = 0; i < lines.Length; i += 1) {
  var line = lines[i];
  // Process line
}
```

but I Can't determine how i can specify the Key and value  
for each line , and how tell the sign

> **

as it's breaker between each object .Any Help

Comment: This is not about Excel, this is about splitting strings into pieces and acting on them. Please make the Title reflect that.

Comment: this apart of my problem that i target if you have reference related of title can read from it your welcome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following code :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApplication87
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.txt";   
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Item items = new Item(FILENAME);
        }
    }
    public class Item
    {
        public static List<Item> items = new List<Item>();
        public string VehicleReferenceKey;
        public string DriverReferenceKey;
        public string Latitude;

        public Item() { }
        public Item(string filenam)
        {
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(filenam);
            string line = "";
            Item newItem = null;
            while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                line = line.Trim();
                if (line.Length > 0)
                {
                    string[] rowItems = line.Split(new char[] { ':' });

                    switch (rowItems[0])
                    {
                        case "VehicleReferenceKey" :
                            newItem = new Item();
                            items.Add(newItem);
                            newItem.VehicleReferenceKey = rowItems[1]; 
                            break;
                        case "DriverReferenceKey":
                            newItem.DriverReferenceKey = rowItems[1];
                            break;
                        case "Latitude":
                            newItem.Latitude = rowItems[1];
                            break;
                    }
                }
            }


        }
    }


}
```

Comment: Excellent That What i need thank you

Answer (score 0):

Basically it seems the following hold for your file:
The first item takes 3 lines (one for each field)
Every item after the first takes 7 lines (2 empty lines, 1 line containing "**", 1 empty line and then the 3 lines with the field values)
So there's no reason to parse the ** and the empty lines you can just skip those (by looping over 7 lines at a time).
For the seperating key and value you can use the [String.Split](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split?view=netframework-4.7.2) method.

All in all it would look something like this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < lines.Length + 2; i += 7)
{
   var newItem = new Item(){
      VehicleReferenceKey = lines[i].Split(':')[1],
      DriverReferenceKey = lines[i+1].Split(':')[1],
      Latitude = lines[i+2].Split(':')[1]
   }
   //do whatever you want with the newItem
}
```