# how to load text from a file and put it into a list using c#

Tags: c#

I have loaded the text from the file
I have outputted each line on to the screen
I have split each string into 3 parts

I am stuck on the next part of adding each part of the string into its relevant list

Okay, so I loaded a line from a text file and split the line into 3 parts and I have 3 variables `a`, `b`, `c` and to each variable I assigned 1st 2nd and 3rd part of the string to that variable respectively like this: `string a = textfromfile[1];` but I want to save each part of the string to a list each but when I write it in the format `list.add(item)` like this: `list.add(textfromfile[1]);` I get an error saying cannot convert from string, why is that?

This is how I declared it and the line below it gets an error saying:

> CS1503  C# Argument 1: cannot convert from 'string' to

```
List<Words> wordlist = new List<Words>();
wordlist.Add(filetext[0]);
```

Comment: Without seeing what you have tried, it is difficult to see why you have difficulties doing this. It's as simple as `list.Add(item)`.

Comment: See my response at following posting : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53591538/try-to-convert-text-file-to-excel/53591848#comment94046838_53591848

Comment: *"I am not able to post my code here"* - That's a bit problematic when you're asking for help with that code.  Imagine calling an auto mechanic on the phone and saying, "My car won't start.  I won't tow it to you, but I was wondering if you had any ideas on how to start a car."  Even if that mechanic wants to help (which we do), you've given him no information about the problem.

Comment: I am not able to post my answer here

Comment: You need to post your code here for people to help. If there's some privacy or copyright issue, then post similar code which reproduces the problem and then apply it to your actual code.

Comment: In your question, please, not the comments.

Comment: In what is this related to adding an entry to a list?

Comment: I think you're missing the point. **Please post a short, compilable code sample that reproduces the problem**, not a description of the code you've written. Also copy/paste the *actual* error message you get. Help us help you.

Comment: You probably get this error, because you are trying to add string to a list which is not a list of strings. But again: Difficult to say, without seeing your code.

Comment: How is your variable `list` defined?  It sounds like it is something other than `List<string>`

Answer (score 0):

As people who commented said, you should add those values into the list using the method `list.Add(item)`.

You said that you have split each string into 3 parts, so I assume that you used `Split(separator)` method. To add the results to your list, simply:

```
yourList = yourString.Split(yourSeparator).ToList();
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the exception because you are attempting to add a `string` to a `List<Words>`. You must add `Words` objects to the list.

I can only guess how `Words` is declared. Let's assume that is declared like this:

```
public class Words
{
    public string A { get; set; }
    public string B { get; set; }
    public string C { get; set; }
}
```

Then you will have to add this to the list:

```
wordlist.Add(new Words{ A = a, B = b, C = c});
```

where `a`, `b` and `c` are your 3 string variables.

But it is really hard to give you a more precise answer, as we still know very little about your code!

If the class was declared as

```
public class Words
{
    public Words(string a, string b, string c)
    {
        A = a;
        B = b;
        C = c;
    }

    public string A { get; }
    public string B { get; }
    public string C { get; }
}
```

Then the code would change to

```
wordlist.Add(new Words(a, b, c));
```